# How can I Make multi select in simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I have written the following to accept roles ,how can make it accept multiple values

```
= f.simple_fields_for :content_roles do |role|
  = role.input :role_id, label: "visible to", as: :select, label: "Role", collection: Role.all, required: true
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `multiple: true` to your role field.

Like this:

```
= role.input :role_id, label: "visible to", as: :select, label: "Role", collection: Role.all, required: true, multiple: true
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that is working in my current online project. Updated missing ruby tag....

Comment: please [edit] you question and fix the code markdown.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for pointing out. But the solution is correct. above solutions dont work. This works..!

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me without fields_for and it should only be used when you have to add a new role in my opinion

you can just do this with preselect values and bootstrap selectpicker:

```rb
    = simple_form_for [:backend, @user], html: { autocomplete: 'off' } do |f|
      = f.select :role_ids, options_for_select(Role.all.map{|role| [role.name, role.id]}, @user.role_ids), {},  {:multiple => true, inlcude_blank: false, class: "form-control input-sm selectpicker"}
```

controler:

```rb
module Backend
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: %i[edit update]
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def edit
      @user.roles.build unless @user.roles.any?
    end

    def update
      if @user.update user_params
        redirect_to backend_users_path(@user), notice: 'Rollen erfolgreich aktualisiert'
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end

    private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, role_ids: [])
    end
  end
end
```